# Combinatorics - 5 digit number

Tags: combinatorics

How many odd numbers with 5 digits there are if:
1.all the digits have to be different from each other
2.Tens digit had to be bigger than the hundreds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Setup:**

In both problems, approach with the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

For the first, use the following steps:

- Pick the final digit.  (*For the overall number to be odd, the final digit must be odd*)
- Pick the first digit.  (*For the overall number to be a five-digit number, the first digit may not be zero.  For all digits to be different, it also cannot be whatever was picked for the final digit*)
- Pick the second digit
- Pick the third digit
- Pick the fourth digit (*Similarly, none of these digits may be the same as any of the previous*)

Multiply the number of options available for each step to get the total number of such numbers are possible.

---

For the second, presumably the condition that all digits must be different from one another is no longer required.

- Pick the final digit (*it must be odd*)
- Pick the first digit (*it cannot be zero*)
- Pick the second digit
- Pick the third and fourth digits simultaneously and put the larger of the two in the fourth slot  (*Binomial coefficients can be a useful tool to count with here*)

Again, multiply the number of options available at each step to get the overall total.

Comment: is there an easy way to do those combinations without separating to a lot of cases. I mean my only problem is with the ten digit and the hundreds. I must say: if 1 was chosen for the tens then the hundreds will be 0. if 2 was chosen then only 1 for the hundreds, and so on....

Comment: @RanHadar I already mentioned for the ten's digit being larger than hundred's digit step that [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) will be useful.  Have you used binomial coefficients before?  Do you see why the number of ways of selecting two digits where one is strictly larger than the other is related to a binomial coefficient here?

Comment: @RanHadar if $1$ was chosen for the tens, the hundreds must be zero.  If $2$ was chosen for the tens, the hundreds could be zero or one.  If $0$ was chosen for the tens, there is no valid choice for the hundreds, and so on... you could just add manually and get $0+1+2+\dots+9$, which you [should know the trick to calculating quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) which again involves binomial coefficients.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thank you very much!